# React gallery App. I want Add tags to an image individually but the tag is being added to all images. How can I solve this?

Tags: reactjs, tags

**>   This is my Gallery Component **

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import useFirestore from '../hooks/useFirestore';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';


const Gallery = ({ setSelectedImg }) => {
  const { docs } = useFirestore('images');
```

> here im setting the state as a Tags array

```
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([""]);

  
  const addTag = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
        setTags([...tags, e.target.value]);
        e.target.value = "";
      }
    }
  };
```

> functions for adding and removing Tags

```
  const removeTag = (removedTag) => {
    const newTags = tags.filter((tag) => tag !== removedTag);
    setTags(newTags);
  };

  return (
    <>
    
      <div className="img-grid">
      {docs && docs.map(doc => (
      
        < motion.div className="img-wrap" key={doc.id} 
          layout
          whileHover={{ opacity: 1 }}s
          onClick={() => setSelectedImg(doc.url)}
        >
```

> here Im adding the Tag input to each Image...the problem is that when adding a Tag is added to all the pictures. I want to add the tags for the image that I´m selecting.

```
        <div className="tag-container">
        {tags.map((tag, ) => {
          return (
            <div key={doc.id} className="tag">
              {tag} <span onClick={() => removeTag(tag)}>x</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}

        <input onKeyDown={addTag} />
      </div>
          <motion.img src={doc.url} alt="uploaded pic"
            initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
            transition={{ delay: 1 }}
          >
           
          </motion.img>
       
        </motion.div>
     
      ))}
    </div>  
     
    </>
  )
}

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: any ideas? I really would appreciate it. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tags` array that you are using to store values entered by the user are not unique with respect to each `image item`. Meaning, every image item in your program is using the same instance of the `tags` array, what you need to do is

1. Either create an object that stores an array of tags for each image:
   `const [tagsObj, setTagsObj] = {}`, then while adding a new tag for say `image_1`, you can simply do `setTagsObj(prevObj => {...prevObj, image_1: [...prevObj?.image_1, newTagValue]}`,
2. Or create an `Image` Component which would then handle tags for a single image:

Gallery Component:

```
{
    imageList.map(imageEl => 
          <ImageItem key={imageEl} image={imageEl} />
        )

}
```

ImageItem Component:

```
import {useState} from 'react';

export default function ImageItem({image}) {
const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

const addTag = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      const newVal = e.target.value;
      if (newVal.length > 0) {
        setTags(prevTags => [...prevTags, newVal]);
        e.target.value = '';
      }
    }
  };

const removeTag = (removedTag) => {
    setTags(prevTags => prevTags.filter((tag) => tag !== removedTag));
  }

  return (    
    <div style={{margin: '12px', padding: '12px', width: '100px', height:'100px', display:'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems:'center'}}>
      <span>{image}</span>
      {tags.map((tag, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={tag+index}>
              {tag} <span onClick={() => removeTag(tag)}>x</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <input onKeyDown={addTag} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Refer this sandbox for ease, if available [Gallery unique image tags sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-antonelli-71804i?file=/src/App.js)

I suggest using the second method, as it is easy to understand and debug later on.
I hope this helps, please accept the answer if it does!